# Print figure of hangman in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

Is there a better way to print a hangman figure?

```
FIG0    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG1    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG2    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/        |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG3    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/ \      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG4    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG5    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG6    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'/        |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG7    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'/ \      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
FIG8    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'   \O/   |',0DH,0AH,'    |    |',0DH,0AH,'    |    |',0DH,0AH,'   / \   |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH,'$'
```

Here is some nice figure. https://youtu.be/e2S_POws3DQ?t=42s

Its look really cool when he jump if you win game. I try to use **call Clrscr** and make him jump, but no luck.

Comment: Yes. There are many possible ways. For example you can stop using BIOS/DOS services to output characters, then you can clear just the area of gallows, print the empty gallows, and then the hangman itself can be encoded as char_at_position, for N steps, and you would use only "n" steps (0 <= n <= N) according to amount of mistakes. So you would have only one gallow in data, and only one hangman. Also you can then draw full N step hangman with +-1 y position to make him jump around... but there're millions of other possibilities, this one is more the "programmer" approach, less data, more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Don't change your environment (Windows, 32-bit, Console, MASM, Irvine32)! You will meet a lot of people who suggest you to change it (Do it with BIOS, MS-DOS, Linux. Do it with GDI, OpenGL, DirectX. And so on.). You might solve a problem better with another environment, but you'll get new problems, which can be solved with changing the environment. At the end you'll quit the whole project - unfinished.

`"$"`is the termination character of a MS-DOS string. In Windows/Irvine32 you handle with a null-termination.

Even the Console mode of Windows is quite quick. So you need Irvine's [`Delay`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fdelay.htm) function to see an animation:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA

FIG0    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG1    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG2    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/        |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG3    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/ \      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG4    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG5    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG6    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'/        |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG7    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,' O       |',0DH,0AH,'/|\      |',0DH,0AH,' |       |',0DH,0AH,'/ \      |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0
FIG8    DB 0DH,0AH,' +=======+',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'         |',0DH,0AH,'   \O/   |',0DH,0AH,'    |    |',0DH,0AH,'    |    |',0DH,0AH,'   / \   |',0DH,0AH,' ========+',0DH,0AH, 0

.CODE

main PROC

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG0
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG1
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG2
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG3
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG4
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr
    lea edx, FIG5
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG6
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG7
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    mov eax, 1000                       ; 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    call Delay                          ; Irvine32: Delay ECX milliseconds
    call ClrScr                         ; Irvine32; Clear Screen
    lea edx, FIG8
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a string pointed to by EDX

    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

main ENDP

END main
```

[`ClrScr`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fclrscr.htm) is not ideal for your purpose since it clears the whole screen including the inputs. Use Irvine's [`GotoXY`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fgotoxy.htm). Delete the old picture by writing spaces.

Comment: Thank you.. I would try do to like that.. :) Are you interesting to write me one code from C to assemly. From another project I was need to write code in C for mikrokontroler MSP430F5438A. But one interrupt must be in assemly.

Comment: @SakaSerbia: I am sorry that I cannot take your offer. I mothballed my LaunchPad years ago. I had to reinstall hardware and software and to refresh my knowledge. I am not interested enough in thie technology and the task to do so. As you can see I don't answer here questions about MSP430 (or AVR or PIC).