# Clears the screen faster in assemly

Tags: assembly, screen, masm, irvine32

I have problem with clearing the screen.

I was using **call Clrscr** but its slow. It is not fast enough, so i have screen, black, with no figure, because of waiting on function Clrscr to finish.

```
    call Clrscr

  ; Write a string to the console:
    INVOKE WriteConsole,
        consoleHandle,              ;console output handle
        ADDR HANGMAN_GOODGAME_00,               ; string pointer
        messageSizeGoodGame,                ; string length
        ADDR bytesWritten,          ; returns num bytes written
        0                           ; not used

    mov eax, drowDelay
    call Delay
    call Clrscr

  ; Write a string to the console:
    INVOKE WriteConsole,
        consoleHandle,              ;console output handle
        ADDR HANGMAN_GOODGAME_01,               ; string pointer
        messageSizeGoodGame,                ; string length
        ADDR bytesWritten,          ; returns num bytes written
        0                           ; not used

    mov eax, drowDelay
    call Delay
    call Clrscr

  ........
```

This is photo. How Its look without slearing. I am trying to make animation..:)

[image]

Comment: Can't you just output enough `newline`s to scroll up out of view? Edit -- sorry I misunderstood, you want the hanged man to wave. How horrible. A text console is not really the right place for animations.

Comment: I know its horrible, but I see that on one youtube.. XD and I want to add that to my project.. :) And this is assemly, Its doble horrible..

Comment: Yeah, well if imitating what you see on youtube is in accordance with your Chinese Proverb, good lucky 7 to you.

Comment: Don't clear the screen.  Overwrite the portions that are animating.

Comment: How to  Overwrite  portions in assembly..? I would try to found some function in irvine..

Comment: SORRY, my advice was wrong, you are doing win32 console exe, not DOS exe.... (I deleted it)

Comment: Duplicate of [Print figure of hangman in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357310/print-figure-of-hangman-in-assembly) (rkhb already told you how to do this: use `GoToXY`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set cursor position. 
Just use setcursorpos from winapi:

```
push 0
push 0
call [SetCursorPos]
```

Its in the user32.dll

Edit: the way it wokrs is simple, you set the cursor position to the top left corner making the feel of movement